# Initiate scan from Fujitsu ix500 to Linux over USB

Tags: linux, usb, scanner

I want to start a scan by pressing the scanner's scan button and have the data delivered to a Linux box.

Unfortunately, I can't use the scanner's WLAN interface, so I'm stuck with USB.

Is there any chance to make this work?

Here's a few speculative ways to achieve this. Did you have success with any of these?

- Run a client on Linux that (partially) adheres to the protocol that's implemented in ScanSnap's Windows and macOS clients (unlikely)
- Install a USB-to-Ethernet adapter on the scanner and get the scanner to use it as an ethernet device. I could then scan to FTP.
- Install the official Windows client via Wine.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166248/how-to-add-double-click-event-in-scanbd-for-ix500-scanner

Answer (score 3):

[scanimage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/scanimage.1.html) supports the ix500 scanner over usb

example:

```
scanimage -L
device `fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:59766' is a FUJITSU ScanSnap iX500 scanner
```

So what's missing it the trigger from the button. I found

https://www.camroncade.com/cloud-scanner-with-raspberry-pi-fujitsu-ix500-2/

mentioning a scannerbuttond package. There is a german description at:

- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/scanbuttond/
  and an english one at
- http://virantha.com/2014/03/17/one-touch-scanning-with-fujitsu-scansnap-in-linux/

Both are a bit outdated but give some hints on the general idea.
Here is a description of a trial with an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS virtual machine.
After installing

```
sudo apt-get install scanbuttond
```

I connected the scanner by assigning it's USB device to the virtual machine.

```
scanimage -L
```

worked as described above.

```
sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04c5 [Fujitsu], product=0x132b [ScanSnap iX500]) at libusb:003:007
could not fetch string descriptor: Input/output error
could not fetch string descriptor: Input/output error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Input/output error
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

looks promising.

```
sudo scanbd -d7 -f
```

starts the daemon in foreground with debugging set to a high level.
In my case i had to comment out some scanner drivers in dll.conf to get rid of results from a different scanner that was available on my network.

Due to bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scanbd/+bug/1747115
I also had to change the users / group settings.

```
diff --git a/scanbd/scanbd.conf b/scanbd/scanbd.conf
index 5d74933..1356236 100644
--- a/scanbd/scanbd.conf
+++ b/scanbd/scanbd.conf
@@ -39,8 +39,8 @@ global {
         # ArchLinux (ArchLinux doesn't have saned user)
         # user    = daemon
         # *BSD
-        # user    = root
-        user    = saned
+        user    = root
+        #user    = saned
```

I added the full path to my test script 5 times in scanbd.conf and 4 times in scanner.d/fujitsu.conf:

```
root@fur:/etc/scanbd# grep scan.sh scanbd.conf 
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
root@fur:/etc/scanbd# cd scanner.d/
root@fur:/etc/scanbd/scanner.d# grep scan.sh fujitsu.conf 
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
                script = "/home/wf/bin/scan.sh"
```

with the script scan.sh being:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2018-12-18
echo "scanning"
echo "scan button pressed on ix500" >> /tmp/ix500.log
```

i then tested with

```
sudo scanbd -f
```

in one terminal and

```
tail -f /tmp/ix500.log
```

in another.

```
scanbd: dbus match type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager'
scanbd: SANE_CONFIG_DIR not set
scanbd: Not Primary Owner (-1)
scanbd: Name Error (Connection ":1.96" is not allowed to own the service "de.kmux.scanbd.server" due to security policies in the configuration file)
scanbd: trigger action for page-loaded for device fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:59766 with script /home/wf/bin/scan.sh
scanning
```

shows on the daemon's foreground output

and

```
scan button pressed on ix500
```

from here it seems be all downhill - the environment variables being passed are described in the scanbd.conf file.

e.g. modifying scan.sh to:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2018-12-18
echo "scanning"
cat << EOF >> /tmp/ix500.log
scan button pressed on ix500
function: $SCANBD_FUNCTION
mode: $SCANBD_FUNCTION_MODE
device: $SCANBD_DEVICE
action: $SCANBD_ACTION
EOF
```

will create

```
scan button pressed on ix500
function: 1
mode: Lineart
device: fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:59766
action: scan
```

on the press of the scan button :-)

Answer (score 2):

Running on Ubuntu 18.04 I was able to get my script starting for my fujitsu snapscan ix500.

Use `sudo apt install scanbd` to install the button daemon. Start `lsusb` to get your scanner usb identifier.

```
$ lsusb 
...
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 04c5:132b Fujitsu, Ltd 
...
```

So I grep for `132b` to find which driver supports my scanner.

```
$ grep 132b /etc/sane.d/*.conf
/etc/sane.d/fujitsu.conf:usb 0x04c5 0x132b
/etc/sane.d/magicolor.conf:# usb 0x132b 0x2098
```

Which is the `fujtisu` driver in my case.

I copied the original configuration like this:

```
sudo cp /etc/sane.d/dll.conf /etc/sane.d/dll.conf.orig
sudo cp /etc/scanbd/dll.conf /etc/scanbd/dll.conf.orig
sudo cp /etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf /etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf.orig
```

Change the `/etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf` to run the service as root instead of saned user and change the action script to my own script.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/scanbd/scanbd.conf
...
        user    = root
        # user    = saned
...
        action scan {
                filter = "^scan.*"
                numerical-trigger {
                        from-value = 1
                        to-value   = 0
                }
                desc   = "Scan to file"
                # script must be an relative path starting from scriptdir (see above),
                # or an absolute pathname.
                # It must contain the path to the action script without arguments
                # Absolute path example: script = "/some/path/foo.script
                # script = "test.script"
                script = "/home/madmike/bin/scan"
        }
...
```

Change the files `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` and `/etc/scanbd/dll.conf` to only contain one line with the name of the driver supporting your scanner. In my case `fujitsu`

```
$ sudo /etc/sane.d/dll.conf
# yada yada comment
# ...
fujitsu


$ sudo /etc/scanbd/dll.conf
# yada yada comment
# ...
fujitsu
```

The easiest way to test the setup is to stop the systemd-daemon and run it in the console.

```
sudo systemctl stop scanbd
sudo scanbd -d7 -f
```

If your script gets called, you can stop scanbd with Ctrl-c in the console and start the daemon again.

```
sudo systemctl start scanbd
```

The question wants to **scan** what is on the scanner. I'll post the script I wrote later with a update to this answer.

I've used this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1385521/42972) and the guide here for [Raspberry-Pi](https://sodocumentation.net/raspberry-pi/topic/6701/create-a-scan-station-with-scanbd--raspbian-) to find this solution.